# How Can I Programmatically Add Multiple Migration Assemblies in EF7 RC2?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core-rc2

In application startup in an ASP .Net Core 1.0 app, I might have something like the following in ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        "MyConnectionString", 
        o => o.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssembly")));
```

That's fine when I only have one assembly I want to track migrations on. But what if I have multiple assemblies (in a plugin scenario) where each plugin might supply its own migration script?

How can I track those multiple migration assemblies? I have a single DbContext.